# mutate a nested tibble with column data of parent tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I got the following data:

```
test1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ company,
  ~ fx,
  ~ data,
  "company1",
  'EUR',
  tibble::tibble(cars[1:2,]),
  "company2",
  'USD',
  tibble::tibble(cars[3:4,]),
  "company3",
  'CHF',
  tibble::tibble(cars[5:6,])
)
```

I can mutate the nested data like this:

```
test2 <- test1 |>
  dplyr::mutate(data = data |> purrr::map(\(x) x |> dplyr::mutate(x, Test ='Test')))

test2$data[[2]] |> names()
```

Now i'm struggling to append the nested data with the fx of the parent data (i.e. EUR,USD,CHF)

Any advice?

Comment: you could also just use `unnest(test1, data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you need is `map2` so that you can pass both `data` as well as `fx` value in the function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

test2 <- test1 |> mutate(data = map2(data, fx, \(x, y) x |> mutate(Test = y)))

test2
#  company  fx    data            
#  <chr>    <chr> <list>          
#1 company1 EUR   <tibble [2 × 3]>
#2 company2 USD   <tibble [2 × 3]>
#3 company3 CHF   <tibble [2 × 3]>

test2$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
#  speed  dist Test 
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1     4     2 EUR  
#2     4    10 EUR  

test2$data[[2]]

# A tibble: 2 × 3
#  speed  dist Test 
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1     7     4 USD  
#2     7    22 USD
```

Comment: Many thanks! I had tried that but messed up the syntax with the new anonymous function and forgot to supply .y. Stupid me!